# MuleSoft Parse Template Reference

Tags: javascript, html, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

I need to send out an email using MuleSoft Email Connector (SMTP) and I'm using parse template to generate the html content. I have request on how to generate rows dynamically, below is the code i have right now.

```
<table style="width:100%" border="1">
  <tr>
  <th bgcolor="lightblue">Id</th>
<th bgcolor="lightblue">App Name</th>
<th bgcolor="lightblue">Error Timestamp</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>#[correlationId]</td>
<td> #[payload.application]</td>
 <td>#[now()]</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

But in my payload i have array of objects #[payload.request], so the row count should be based on payload.request. How do i do that ?

Comment: That is HTML, I would not call it code exactly. It is not clear if it is an example input or output. You should share whatever DataWeave script you have, or flow, if any. I don't see any rows. What is exctly the input (payload.request) and what is the expected output?

Answer (score 3):

Let's say your payload is

```
{ request: [
  { application: "app1"},
  { application: "app2"}
]}
```

You can use DataWeave to create the full table. You need to start from `table` and not `tr` because the output xml must have a single root node.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/xml writeDeclaration=false
var time = now()
---
{
    table @(style: "width:100%", border: "1"): {
        tr: {
            th @(bgcolor: "lightblue"): "Id",
            th @(bgcolor: "lightblue"): "App Name",
            th @(bgcolor: "lightblue"): "Error Timestamp"
        },
        (payload.request map (item, c) -> {
            tr: {
                td: correlationId,
                td: item.application,
                td: time
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Then, you can embed that output into a bigger HTML like this

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>#[payload]</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Liked this solution..Can you share any links for any css properties that can be applied in transform message connector? like font-color, border-color etc etc coz normal css properties does not work in transform message

Comment: We are just creating raw HTML/XML so any should work. You need to put them inside `style`. Something like `@(style: "color:blue;font-size:20px;text-align:center;")`